# Fluent-NHibernate many-to-many cascade does not populate the link table

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

OK, no matter how I define these mappings, my many-to-many mapping does not want to work with cascade insert. I have tried various combination of `Cascade()` with `Reverse()` and removing all unnecessary properties just to understand if they had anything to do with this not working, but no lock.

It is really Simple stuff: I have a `Message` (like an email) which is sent from a user (I have called the entity `BasicUser`) to a number of users (through property `To`). `User` and `Message` in terms of recipients have a many-to-many relationship but `FromUser` has one-to-many. FromUser works fine and it is updated alright but my problem is with many-to-many. I even removed `FromUser` and relationship just to check if this was the problem, but did not help.

So here is the table design (Have removed the relationship from `FromUser` to `BasicUser` for simplicity)

[image]

And here are the mappings:

```
public class MessageMap : ClassMap<Message>
{

    public MessageMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("MessageId");
        Map(x => x.Subject);
        Map(x => x.SentAt);
        Map(x => x.Body);
        References(x => x.From).Column("FromUser");
        HasManyToMany(x => x.To).Table("BasicUserMessage").ChildKeyColumn("BasicUserId")
            .ParentKeyColumn("MessageId").Cascade().All();
    }
}

public class BasicUserMap : ClassMap<BasicUser>
{
    public BasicUserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).Column("BasicUserId");
        Map(x => x.DisplayName);
        Map(x => x.Username);
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Messages).Table("BasicUserMessage").ChildKeyColumn("MessageId")
            .ParentKeyColumn("BasicUserId").Inverse();
    }
}
```

And I call this and it does not work (table `BasicUserMessage` does not get populated):
(Note Users with Id 1, 2 and 3 do exist - I also tried getting them from database and then add to list still did not work)

```
ISessionFactory factory = GetSessionFactory();
ISession session = factory.OpenSession();
Message m = new Message()
                {
                    Body = "Please note 2",
                    Subject = "Secret 2",
                    From = new BasicUser(){Id = 2},
                    SentAt = DateTime.Now,
                };
m.To.Add(new BasicUser(){Id = 1});
m.To.Add(new BasicUser(){Id=3});
session.SaveOrUpdate(m);
session.Close();
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer about transactions is correct-by-incidental-occurrence. Also correct-by-incidental occurrence is that this is manifesting itself as such because you are using something like an `IDENTITY` generator that requires a database trip on save to obtain the identity.

Here is what NHibernate does when you set a `save-update` cascade (or any cascade which implies that) on a many-to-many association with such:

Save the parent entity. This goes to the database immediately because of the identity strategy. The collection is "modified" (because it's new), so let's look at it's members. This step only occurs if `inverse` is not set on the parent's mapping of the relationship. Create an entry in the link table for each of them.

But wait, some of these entries are transient. Cascades are set properly, so that's okay - but in order to create the link table entry in the session, we need the id of those children, so let's save them immediately.

Now all relevant entities are persistent, and the session has a *pending insert* for all of the entries in the link table. Flushing the session will issue the commands and create those entries.

When you wrap your code in a transaction, committing the transaction flushes the session, so that is created when you commit. If you use an identity generator that doesn't require a DB round-trip, then the link table entries and the entities are all inserted at the same time, so you won't see the "disconnect" that you're seeing - if the session is never flushed, nothing is ever inserted, and when it is flushed, everything is inserted. If you have neither of these things, flushing your session explicitly will create the link table entries and all will be well.

Answer (score 5):

You made both references inverse. This means to NH: don't store it from this side, because it is already stored by the other side. If both are inverse, nothing is stored.

Remove Inverse from one of the references.

Comment: I have tested allllllllllllll sorts. I have tested with one `Invers()` but you are right, for the sake of question it must be clean and I removed it.

Comment: It seems I had forgotten to remove the `Inverse()`. I removed the extra one.

Comment: And are both references consistent in memory? NH stores what you have in memory, and if it is inconsistent, you get weird results.

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap your code in transaction. Otherwise Nhibernate won't save values in joining table

Comment: Your answer is wrong. It has nothing to do with transactions... please delete it.

Comment: Have you tried what he suggested? The lack of a transaction is often the cause of these kind of issues. Also, an incorrect answer does not need to be deleted (and can be useful for other people who come across this question at a later date).

Comment: I answered this not just to answer. I had similar issue and transaction did help...

Comment: @James, is there a working example of many-to-many relationship which updates the  joint table? If so can you please point me to it?

Comment: @Sly, thanks. Well you are right - in a real world scenario I would have used a transaction. But the fact that NHibernate would require a transaction to work really confuses me. :( To be frank I am getting really disappointed by NH.

Comment: :) Well, I wish. If only it would have solved my problem. I am surprised, anyone could point me to a working example?

Comment: Sly is right. It worked for me when wrapped it in a transaction. Be sure to commit your transaction at the end of the scope. Consider this example, tables `JobSite` and `Person`. The many-table was called `JobSitePerson` and contained two columns: `JobSiteId` and `PersonId`. Unlike your example I used Cascade on both sides, not sure if this matters. Similar to your example I had inverse on one side and specified the table name. Unlike your example, I didnt specify ParentKeyColumn/ChildKeyColumn, the default settings worked. Dont be discouraged Nhibernate is great if wielded properly.

Comment: Not completely true: Session.Flush() is absolutely sufficient to handle child records that go along with the primary entity. Since ITransaction.Commit does the same thing under the hood, it's OK to use (and transaction safety is, btw, a good addendum anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the BasicUser objects persistent:

```
ISessionFactory factory = GetSessionFactory();
ISession session = factory.OpenSession();
Message m = new Message()
                {
                    Body = "Please note 2",
                    Subject = "Secret 2",
                    From = new BasicUser(){Id = 2},
                    SentAt = DateTime.Now,
                };
var basicUser1 = new BasicUser(){Id = 1};
session.Save(basicUser1);
m.To.Add(basicUser1);
var basicUser3 = new BasicUser(){Id = 3};
session.Save(basicUser3);
m.To.Add(basicUser3);
session.Save(m);
session.Flush();
```

This should of course be done in a transaction (as Sly answered) and the session should be wrapped in a using statement.

Comment: Hi Jamie, As I mentioned, database contains BasicUser Ids of 1, 2 and 3. **They are already in database.**

Comment: This is a simplified harness, not a repository. Of course, in repository pattern I would have an IUnitOfWork which would be created in a `using` statement.

Comment: Your code is creating new BasicUsers, not retrieving them from the database. If you tried getting them from the database then it's your inverse settings as Stefan said.

Comment: I have done it that way as well. Just read the question carefully, would you?